# Set value conditionally within groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to set a value in my data set based on a condition of a groupby. The `val` should show only if it is the largest one in its group, otherwise I want to display a `0`.

So:

```
id     val    
1      3
1      2
1      4
2      1
2      5
3      4
```

Should become:

```
id     val    
1      0
1      0
1      4
2      0
2      5
3      4
```

I tried something like this:

```
def f(x):
    if x == max(x):
        return x
    else:
        return 0

train.groupby("id")["val"].transform(f)
```

However, this does give me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set values by condition:

```
df.loc[df.groupby("id")["val"].transform('max').ne(df['val']), 'val'] = 0
print (df)
   id  val
0   1    0
1   1    0
2   1    4
3   2    0
4   2    5
5   3    4
```

**Details**:

```
#get max value to Series
print (df.groupby("id")["val"].transform('max'))
0    4
1    4
2    4
3    5
4    5
5    4
Name: val, dtype: int64

#compare for not equal with original values
print (df.groupby("id")["val"].transform('max').ne(df['val']))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: val, dtype: bool
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
def f(x):
    return np.where(x == x.max(), x, 0)

print (df.groupby("id")["val"].transform(f))
```

What should be rewritten like:

```
#equal by eq
df['val'] = np.where(df.groupby("id")["val"].transform('max').eq(df['val']), df['val'], 0)

#not equal by ne - swapped arguments
df['val'] = np.where(df.groupby("id")["val"].transform('max').ne(df['val']), 0, df['val'])
```

Than you, @Chris A for solution with multiple:

```
df['val'] = df.groupby('id')['val'].transform('max').eq(df.val).mul(df.val)
```

Comment: could use `train['val'] = train.groupby('id')['val'].transform('max').eq(train.val).mul(train.val)` instead of `np.where`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` as well:

```
df['val'] = df.groupby('id').val.apply(lambda x: (x==x.max())*x.max())
```

Output:

```
    id  val
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   4
3   2   0
4   2   5
5   3   4
```